# Type of RF Coil

Tags: rf

I am trying to source parts for a project (Listed Below) and unsure what kind of RF Coil the blogger is mentioning. I am a novice and have managed to source most the other parts but this one component I am having difficulty finding online.. maybe I dont understand what he is using this componant for.. sorry told you I was a novice!

[Wide-Band Analog White-Noise Generator](https://www.electronicdesign.com/test-amp-measurement/wide-band-analog-white-noise-generator)

Comment: The component is marked "RF coil" in the schematic, how helpful (not). Since it is simply used as a choke (pass DC but block AC) almost any coil larger than 10 uH will do. Something like this: https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/10-Stks-Ringkern-Spoel-Draad-Wind-Wound-180uH-190-mOhm-1A-Coil/32835888366.html  for example. If you have a coil from a DCDC converter, that will do as well.

Comment: Cool thanks.. if I attached an attenna to this would it essencially create noise in the specified range? (sorry again for my noobness)

Comment: Also do you have any explaination why he wants to do this? the right part of the circuit is confusing..

Comment: If you connect the presented noise generator to an antenna, it will spread noise only in the usable frequency band of the antenna. All simple antennas will be either narrow band devices (=work only at a single frequency + some narrow band around it) or they are hopeless power wasters in transmitter applications. The total output power -60dBm isn't much when it's distributed to 50MHz wide band.  It's designed to be connected directly to some device under test. I must admit I have not an idea what a novice would do with it? Band 0...50MHz is well below most generally used radios (=wifi, phones)

Comment: Reword your question as "What characteristics do I need to consider for this coil when finding a substitute for....." otherwise this will be closed as a shopping question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bimpelrekkie points out, the coil is being used as a "choke" to supply power to the amplifier, so its value is not particularly critical. However, there are some details that you need to pay attention to if you want good performance from such a wideband circuit:

- The value must be high enough to not affect the loading of the amplifier at the lowest frequency of interest. If we assume that the output impedance is 50Ω we want the choke impedance to be >10× that value, or 500Ω. The 10 µH suggested by Bimpelrekkie is a bit low — this gives you a lower working frequency of about 800 kHz, with the -3 dB point being around 80 kHz. I would probably go with something more like 100 µH, for a -3 dB point at 8 kHz.
- The impedance of the choke rises with frequency — to a point. When you reach the self-resonant frequency, the impedance starts to drop again. You need to make sure that the high-frequency response extends to the bandwidth of the filter (50 MHz in this example. In other words, the self-resonant frequency of the choke needs to be greater than the geometric mean of the lowest and highest frequencies of interest.

  $$f_{SR} > \sqrt{f_1 \cdot f_2}$$

  Continuing with this example, this would mean that your choke needs to have a self-resonant frequency greater than \$\sqrt{8 kHz \cdot 50 MHz} = 632 kHz\$. (This represents an equivalent parallel capacitance of about 630 pF, which sounds practical.)

Such a choke may or may not be easy to find; I haven't looked myself.

Comment: You'll want to avoid resonance in this "RF choke". Thus add some parallel resistance, perhaps 1Kohm. If you know the capacitance on the RF node, perhaps 100pF (including any PI matching), then a useful dampening value is sqrt (L / C). If 10uH and 100pF, or 1e-5 / 1e-10 or 1e+5, then 330 ohms should be useful. In parallel.